# How to retrieve an img src from a gallery of images using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am building a gallery, where I need to be able to click an image and Jquery code retrieves the source of clicked image, so that I can manipulate it later. The problem is, I can only retrieve image src of a particular image, but not any one among a list of images.
My markup is:

```
    <div class="row normally gallery">
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sx-6 col-sm-6 thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="{{asset('images/projects/nccamh.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive projects" alt="NCCAMH.ORG"/><p class="caption">NCCAMH.ORG</p></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sx-6 col-sm-6 thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="{{asset('images/projects/sewatrust.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive projects" alt="NCCAMH.ORG"/><p class="caption">Sewa Trust</p></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sx-6 col-sm-6 thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="{{asset('images/projects/pdf.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive projects" alt="NCCAMH.ORG"/><p class="caption">PDF Sindh</p></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sx-6 col-sm-6 thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="{{asset('images/projects/wejourno.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive projects" alt="NCCAMH.ORG"/><p class="caption">PDF Sindh</p></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sx-6 col-sm-6 thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="{{asset('images/projects/sso.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive projects" alt="NCCAMH.ORG"/><p class="caption">Sujag Sunsar Organization</p></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sx-6 col-sm-6 thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="{{asset('images/projects/sursociety.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive projects" alt="NCCAMH.ORG"/><p class="caption">Sur Society</p></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sx-6 col-sm-6 thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="{{asset('images/projects/dailysindh.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive projects" alt="NCCAMH.ORG"/><p class="caption">Daily Sindh</p></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sx-6 col-sm-6 thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="{{asset('images/projects/sawail.jpg')}}" class="img-responsive projects" alt="NCCAMH.ORG"/><p class="caption">Sawail</p></a>
</div>
</div>
```

*and the Jquery code is:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.gallery').click(function() {
var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
alert(src);
});
});
```

on whatever image I click within this div, it gives me the img src of only the first image. What should I do, so that It click on either image and it yields the correct img src. 
ps: I tried an another but it yields 'undefined' value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    alert(src);
    });
    });
```

**FAILED**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write event of div with class thumbnail:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.thumbnail').click(function() {
      var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
      alert(src);
    });
  });
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.gallery').on('click','.thumbnail',function() {
          var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
          alert(src);
        });
      });
```

or on image event directly:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
        $('.gallery').on('click','.img-responsive',function() {
          var src = $(this).attr('src');
          alert(src);
        });
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ehsan, however, I already tried your approach, this of event div with $(.'thumbnail') or $('.img-responsive'). It just gives an 'undefined' value. Confused!!

Comment: Wow @Ehsan, this worked: 
$('.gallery').on('click','.img-responsive',function() {
 var src = $(this).attr('src');
  alert(src);
   });
Thanks a million. But I couldn't really understand the syntax of this: .on('click','.img-responsive',function()
??? can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.gallery img').click(function() {
    console.log(this.src);
});
```

Or if your images are loaded dynamically and `.gallery` element is static:

```
$('.gallery').on('click', 'img', function() {
    console.log(this.src);
});
```

**NOTE:** `this.src` will be faster than `$(this).attr('src')` or `$(this).prop('src')`.

Comment: Thanks @VisioN, but the same 'undefined' error with your approach.

Comment: @Zafar Did you try the second approach, which was proposed in the answer?

Comment: Yes @Vision, with a little tweak in it, it worked very well. So, now the point is: $(this).find('img').attr('src') does not work, rather, $(this).attr('src') or console.log(this.src) works. You are really great guys. Thanks

Comment: @Zafar This is because `.find()` searches for element in `this` descendants, while `this.src` or `$(this).attr('src')` picks the value directly from `this` element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.gallery img').on('click',function() {
var src = $(this).attr('src');
alert(src);
});
});
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/22ht5fkr/

Comment: Dear @Tushar, yes you are right. I also tried this, and it wonderfully worked. Great :)

Comment: @Zafar Just wondered, how is this answer different from mine, posted 12 minutes before?

Comment: @VisioN Read my comment to you below your answer.

Comment: @Zafar is my answer not suitable for you ? you deselected my answer :P

Comment: Sorry, I've got internet slow connection problem @Tushar :)

Comment: my answer again got deselected .... please tick it so that it is helpful to others also ..Thanks :)

Comment: @Zafar This *absolutely* doesn't answer my question. Why the code from this answer *"wonderfully worked"*, as the same code from my answer didn't work? I don't see the logic behind.

Comment: There is no point of getting into fight just on the grounds of being who coded right or wrong @VisioN . You can't object anyone like this and you have no rights to force anyone to dislike someone's opinion just because he doesn't like yours .

Comment: @TusharRaj You write nonsense, as my comments refer to understanding what is wrong with my answer. I don't care about the reputation and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('.thumbnail a img').click(function() {

  var src = $(this).attr('src');

   alert(src);

   });

});
```